# how to manipulate multiple dataframes and store the values in a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following situation:

I have multiple tables that look like this:

```
table1 = pd.DataFrame([[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1]], columns=['v1','v2'])
```

I have one dataframe that each element refers to these tables, something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([table1, table2, table3, table4], columns=['tablename'])
```

I need to create a new column in df that contains, for each table, the values that I get from `np.polyfit(table1['v1'],table1['v2'],1)`

I have tried to do the following

```
for x in df['tablename']:
    df.loc[:,'fit_result'] = np.polyfit(x['v1'],x['v2'],1)
```

but it returns me

```
 TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Is there a way to do it? or am I writing something that makes no sense?

obs: in fact, these tables are HUGE and contains more than two columns.

Comment: According to the error you get, I would say that `x` is actually a string representative of a variable name like `'table1'`. so you can try using eval: `np.polyfit(eval(x+"['v1']"),eval(x+"['v2']"),1)`. but I'm not sure it is a good practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


table1 = pd.DataFrame([[0.0,0.0],[1.0,0.8],[2.0,0.9],[3.0,0.1],[4.0,-0.8],[5.0,-1.0]], columns=['table1_v1','table1_v2'])

df = pd.DataFrame([['some','random'],['values','here']], columns=['example_1','example_2'])

def fit_result(v1,v2):
    return np.polyfit(v1, v2, 1)

df['fit_result'] = df.apply(lambda row: fit_result(table1['table1_v1'].values,table1['table1_v2'].values), axis=1)

df.head()
```

Output

```
example_1   example_2   fit_result
0   some    random  [-0.3028571428571428, 0.7571428571428572]
1   values  here    [-0.3028571428571428, 0.7571428571428572]
```

You only need do this over all your dataframes and concat all off them at the end

df_col = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1) (https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/joining-dataframes-pandas)